# Refactoring statement from windsor to structuremap

Tags: c#-4.0, castle-windsor, structuremap

I have the below windsor statement and trying to convert it into a structuremap statement. I really can't find any suggestion how to do it.

```
Container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().
    BasedOn<IType>().If(MatchStatement).Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient.
    Named(c.Implementation.Name)));
```

Anyone knows how this is written with structuremap?

EDIT: To make it more clear.. I've got the statement above (almost anyway) written with Windsor Castle but as we will be using Structuremap instead I need to do the same but with Structuremap. I got pieces of it but not all;

```
        Registry.Scan(x =>
                          {
                              x.TheCallingAssembly();
                              x.AddAllTypesOf<IType>();
                              //{What more?}
                          });
```

What I further need is to meet the MatchStatement condition and return the named instance.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to register and connect all implentations for IType with a specific name using the transient lifecycle?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It also needs to meet the condition MatchStatement (bool expression) This is since we are moving from Windsor to Structuremap. The most troublesome have been the condition part.

Comment: What does the condition do? Is it a bool?

Comment: Yes, the condition is returning a bool, true/false

Comment: So you only want register the types when what happens?! Is it a conditional configuration for the lifecycle? So per default all implementations are singleton (CastleWindsor) and when the condition equals true the life cycle is transient?

Comment: Rookian, yes when my condition is true the lifecycle of my object should be transient and yes, by default the implementations are singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StructureMap's default lifecycle is PerGraph (a mix of transient and singleton).

The following code scans the calling assembly and adds all implentations of `IType` and each implementation is registered with the name of the implementation.

```
Scan(scan =>
{
    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
    scan.AddAllTypesOf<IType>().NameBy(type => type.Name);      
});
```